# Configurar formulário para impressão

Tags: html, css, html5

Criei um formulário em que ao ser preenchido, ele deverá ser impresso. Porém, quando vou imprimir, ele sai todo sem formatação.

Alguém sabe me informar como faço para que a impressão saia formatada?

E como faço para ocultar os botões de enviar, imprimir e apagar? Usei o "display none", mas eles somem no form.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

HTML dos botões:

```
<input class="envio" type="submit" value="Enviar" name="enviar"/>
<button class="apaga" type="reset" value="Apagar">Apagar</button>

                   <head>
                       <script language="JavaScript">

                           <!-- Begin
                           function varitext(text){
                               text=document
                               print(text)
                           }
                           //  End -->
                       </script>

                   </head>
                   <body>

                   <div class="print">
                       <form>
                           <input name="print" type="button" value="Imprimir"
                                  ONCLICK="varitext()">

                       </form>
                   </DIV>
```

Comment: Posta o HTML pra gente ver.

Comment: Acrescentei o html dos botões na pergunta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Utilize o CSS para formatar a impressão, através de um arquivo específico para formatação ou marque as alterações para impressão com o `@media print`:

```
<!-- arquivo CSS específico para impressão -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/print.css" media="print" />
```

ou

```
/* marcar a impressão em arquivo CSS*/

@media print {
}
```

Leia mais sobre [**formatação com CSS para impressão**](http://tableless.com.br/dicas-de-css-para-impressao/)

Comment: Deu super certo! Obrigada!!!